# Windows Phone Custom Control Design and Implementation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am working on a windows phone app, in which I will need to add a costom "cover-flow" kind of control like how it looks like in the Spotify app below:
[image]

Note: user can swipe from right to left to change song.
I don't think Windows Phone SDK provide any controls support this, so I was wondering how such a thing is implemented.

I think it is either faked by a pivot page with dynamically adding/deleting pivot items, or maybe it is a custom control.

If I want to implement this as a custom control, does anyone has experience about it, or any sample code/tutorial will be very helpful.

Thank you

Comment: There is a control within Telerik's phone controls called the SlideView that does this.

Comment: @ShawnKendrotThank you. It looks like I need to pay a lot of money to get this control kit. Is there a free way to implement such a thing?

Comment: It's only $99. You can get it for free if you sign up for the Nokia Premium Developer Program. You also get a free token for the Phone Store to create (or renew) a publisher account and an account with Buddy.com. (FYI It costs $99 to create a publisher account through MS, so you get a lot of stuff for free). Totally worth it!

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at a [Panorama control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941104%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). It is available out of the box with the Windows Phone SDK.

Comment: I don't think this is a panorama page, since the page itslef is not srolling, it is only the album cover scrolling. I believe this is something more like a list.

Comment: There are several implementations for that. You can have a scrollable item container or a Panorama, whichever fits your needs best.

Answer (score 0):

[Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx) makes a great control that does just this. It's called the [SlideView](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/slideview.aspx) control. I know it's not free, but it is only $99. Given that it might take you about 4-10 hours to create this control yourself, I'd say it's worth it. If you join the [Nokia Premium Developer Program](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx#join-nokia) you get Telerik's controls for free.

Note: I do not work for Nokia or Telerik and this is NOT a paid advertisement :)

Answer (score 0):

The swipping effect is because of Panorama page. to change music you need to handle gestures that will be a tough task . The solution is to find a hack or have some control in the background that registers the touch event and changes the music